# How to start a while loop at row 1 after already done a php fetch

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, while-loop

I want to fetch data from the database and use the first row initially. Then later if some values are true I want to loop through all of the rows.

The problem is that the while loop starts at the second row.

Is there a way to make the loop start at the first row?

Below is simplified example:

```
<?php
//GET THE CONNECTION DATA FOR $CONNECTION
require_once('../connect.php');

$get_data = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM db WHERE email = :email');
$get_data -> execute(['email' => 'john@doe.com']);

$data = $get_data->fetch();
echo $data->email;
echo '<br>';

while($data = $get_data->fetch())
{
    //STARTS AT THE SECOND ROW BUT NEEDS TO BE THE FIRST ROW
    echo $data->last_name;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: FYI, do-while loops exist in PHP, too …

Comment: What do you get in you `var_dump($get_data->fetch());` ? And if you do a fetch, won't you just get one row ? So why do a while loop ?

Comment: Yes but the loop still starts at row 2 @04FS

Comment: Yes, but that does not matter, since you have the data from the first record in $data already …

Comment: I'll get multiple rows with the above code @MickaëlLeger

Comment: Are you sure you don't get ONE row (fetch return one row : https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) with multiple fields (email, last_name,...) ? Can you edit your question and add a `var_dump($data)` before the while loop and then inside to see what you get ?

Comment: That is absolutely right :-). I get one row for every fetch. So when I do the first fetch I get the first row. That is why I get the second, third and so on in the while loop. I would just want the while loop to start fetch at the first row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can use `fetchAll()`

```
$results = $get_data->fetchAll ();
$data = $results[0];
echo $data->email;
echo '<br>';

foreach($results as $data) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need something like this, you are doing something wrong.

For the question stated in the title, Dharman's answer is correct and should be accepted for sake of future visitors.

However, in your particular case, you don't need the first fetch and most likely don't need a while loop.

The first fetch is not needed because it is used to output the data you already have (the email used to query the database).
The while loop is not needed because most likely there is only one record in the database with such email, so you can just echo the username right away.

Either way, a sane version of your code would be either

```
$get_data = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM db WHERE email = :email');
$get_data -> execute(['email' => 'john@doe.com']);

$data = $get_data->fetch();
echo $data->email;
echo '<br>';
echo $data->last_name;
echo '<br>';
```

or (in case your query indeed returns multiple rows)

```
$email = 'john@doe.com';
$get_data = $connection->prepare('SELECT * FROM db WHERE email = :email');
$get_data -> execute(['email' => $email]);

echo $email;
echo '<br>';

while($data = $get_data->fetch())
{
    echo $data->last_name;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

See - you **never** need to "restart" the while loop.

Comment: The example is just a simplified version to Illustrated the need. The email is just an example. It could be an id for multiple rows to connect them. So the "email" might show up multiple times in the database. So I first want to do some actions with the fetched data. Then depending on if some other variables are true I want to run a while loop on all rows. That is why I want the while loop to start with the first row

Comment: But as you wrote Dharman's answer is correct and works great :-D!